# Arquillian and jboss-4.2.3.GA

Tags: jboss, jboss-arquillian

i am workign on a jboss-4.2.3.GA project. Its a old project but we cant upgrade to new server.

I am trying to use Arquillian for JPA..

We are using folliwng entry in pom for JPA

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jboss</groupId>
   <artifactId>ejb3-persistence.jar</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.3</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.4.SP1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

I am trying to configure Arquillian but i am getting some issue like nosuchmethod found or some time no default container set.

Anyone help me what container i need to set and any dependency settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the arquillian-bom to the dependencyManagement section of your pom, see the Getting Started Guide: http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/#add_the_arquillian_apis

That will update the version of the dependencies the jbossas adapter has on arquillian core. Without it you will be running a mix of Core 1.0.1.Final and Core X (what ever the adapter happens to be compiled against currently which may or may not be compatible with the 1.0.1.Final Core artifacts).